# append mode is working but write mode is not working when i try to write text file using php in linux server

Tags: php, linux

Code in append mode

```
$target_dir ="status.txt";
$handle = fopen($target_dir, 'a') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$target_dir);
$data = '0';
fwrite($handle, $data);
```

Code in write  mode

```
$target_dir ="status.txt";
$handle = fopen($target_dir, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$target_dir);
$data = '0';
fwrite($handle, $data);
```

I gave full permission of status.txt file but write mode is not working

Comment: Did you wrote file address correctly?

Comment: What's the output when you try - Write Mode ?

Comment: yes . thats why append mode is working . but when i replace 'a' with 'w'  is not working .

Comment: before runing code status.txt file has 1 wrriten into it . After appending 0  status.txt has 10 but i try to write 0 status.txt file is empty

Comment: use this fclose($target_dir); may be previously opened file is in your cahce

Comment: Interesting thing. the code works on Windows, without `fclose($target_dir);` which is a bit strange. In my experiance if you leave a file hande open it usually leads to bad things.

Comment: after adding fclose is not working. status.txt file is still empty.
$target_dir ="status.txt";
$handle = fopen($target_dir, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$target_dir);
$data = '0';
fwrite($handle, $data);
fclose($handle);

Comment: Out of curiosity try writing `$data = "0"`. Also who has the ownership of the file?

Comment: root is owner of status.txt file

Comment: Interesting, i will be checking this on a VM later, have no Linux right now. The problem lies somwhere in the combined: permissions, owner, group  and the user that launches the script. There might be some errors in php_error_log, that will make the situation a bit more understandable.